# Download text file from an external URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to download a text file hosted on a server.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>File</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://example.com/test.txt" download>Click here</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

With the above code, instead of downloading the file, I am being redirected to the text file. How do I rectify this?

Comment: What browser (version) are you using?

Comment: The browser being used is Google Chrome, Version 70.0.3538.110

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes

> `download`
>
> > This attribute only works for same-origin URLs.

Answer (score 0):

It can only download the same file, give you two solutions

**Solution A:** You pack your files to. `zip/. Rar` and other browsers cannot open the file download.

**Solution B:** forwarded by the back - end, back - end request third-party resources, returned to the front end, front-end using tools such as file-saver save the file.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN, using Javascript

```
<a onclick="saveFile('url')">Download</a>

<script>
    function saveFile(url) {
    // Get file name from url.
    var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1).split("?")[0];
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response); // xhr.response is a blob
        a.download = filename; // Set the file name.
        a.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        delete a;
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.send();
    }
</script>
```

the `saveFile('url')` takes `string` url as an argument so pass in the correct url and your file will download directly. Worked for me